# Unable to send email in Lemoon CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, lemoon

The following error appears when trying to send email via LemoonCMS Test email page.

"Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Access denied"

The web.config settings is correct, as i uploaded a custom page using the same settings and its works fine.

The following error taken from the LOG:
2014-08-03 13:38:48.9950|INFO|Mindroute.Core.BootStrapper|Startup completed in 674ms
2014-08-03 13:38:49.2790|INFO|Mindroute.Core.Services.MailService|Sending mail 'Lemoon test message' to 'mfaris@kanzit.com'
2014-08-03 13:38:55.9600|INFO|Mindroute.Core.Services.MailService|Sending mail 'Lemoon test message' to 'mfaris@kanzit.com'
2014-08-03 13:39:09.1240|INFO|Mindroute.Core.BootStrapper|Shutting down. Reason: ConfigurationChange
2014-08-03 13:39:09.1290|INFO|Mindroute.Core.FullText.LuceneFullTextProvider|Disposing FullTextIndex
2014-08-03 13:39:09.1290|INFO|Mindroute.Core.BootStrapper|Shutdown completed in 6ms

Answer (score 0):

Lemoon uses the settings from the MailDaemon when sending email. Have you checked that it is configured correctly? Otherwise it sounds from the error like the problem is with the mail server and not with Lemoon.

Comment: I check the settings in the mailDaemon and i'm sure all my values are correct. What can be the problem, Please advise...

Comment: Like I said, the error seems to be with the mail server and not with Lemoon. Maybe you could try another mail server?